# Type mismatch in persistent

Tags: haskell, yesod

I am having issues with types matching up in persistent. I have a module called Storage.Mongo like so:

```
type FieldMap = Map.Map T.Text T.Text

let mongoSettings = (mkPersistSettings (ConT ''MongoBackend)) {mpsGeneric = False}
    in share [mkPersist mongoSettings] [persistLowerCase|
    Notice
        rawData FieldMap
        deriving Show
    |]

-- | This is the default database pool
defaultPool = createMongoDBPool
            "system_of_record"
            "localhost"
            (PortNumber 33107)
            (Just (MongoAuth "reader" "password"))
            10
            10
            30

-- | Save notice to database
saveNotices x = do pool <- defaultPool
                   runMongoDBPoolDef save pool
                   where save = mapM_ (insert.Notice) x
```

I am trying to pass the saveNotices command a field map, which it will convert to a Notice entity and save to a MongoDb database. To wit:

```
main = do files <- getArgs
          mapM_ parseNotice files
          where parseNotice f = do x <- parseFromFile fboFile f
                                   case x of
                                    Left err -> print err
                                    Right notices -> mapM_ saveNotices notices
```

The parseNotice function returns a list of Maps:

```
notice = do noticeType <- openingTag
            fields <- manyTill (try complexField <|> simpleField) (try closingTag)
            return $ (Map.fromList(concat ([("NOTICETYPE", noticeType)]:fields)))

fboFile = many notice
```

I am not sure where the problem is.  I believe I should let the compiler the know the type of

```
mapM_ (insert.Notice) x
```

is, but I am not sure what the type should be

This is the error I am getting

> Couldn't match type 'PersistEntityBackend Notice' with 'MongoBackend'  Expected type: PersistEntityBackend Notice Actual type: PersistMonadBackend (Action m)  In the first argument of '(.)', namely 'insert' In the first argument of 'mapM_', namely '(insert . Notice)' In the expression: mapM_ (insert . Notice) x

Comment: It helps to call out the line that errored in your code with a comment and include the exact error message encountered.

Comment: I don't believe I have the permission to edit the question, but the error I am getting is:

`Couldn't match type 'PersistEntityBackend Notice' with 'MongoBackend'

Expected type: PersistEntityBackend Notice
Actual type: PersistMonadBackend (Action m)

In the first argument of '(.)', namely 'insert'
In the first argument of 'mapM_', namely '(insert . Notice)'
In the expression: mapM_ (insert . Notice) x
`

Comment: There is an edit link right below the tags for the question. You can always (to my knowledge) edit your own questions/answers. I went ahead and added it for you.

Answer (score 1):

It is failing trying to apply `insert . Notice` (space added for emphasis)

```
insert :: MonadIO' m => Collection -> Document -> Action m Value
type Collection = Text
```

It looks like `insert` expects a name as its first argument. The following might work.

```
mapM_ (insert "Notice" $ Notice) x
```